# Integrating google form with external api

Tags: api, stack-overflow, google-forms, zapier

i want to accomplish whenever a new response to google form comes in , it should trigger an external api which is given by using webhooks by zapier but it is raising an error

[image: error:Failed to create a request in Webhooks by Zapier]

i made a get call to an api in action when a new response to google form is triggered i want to fetch the data from that api but it is saying no data is found and connectiontimeout when i tested the action  i understand that the connection attempt was made, but the server did not respond within the allotted time but don't know how to rectify this error. Can someone please help me out?